# How to fix "login: no shell: No such file or directory" when I can not even login?

Tags: shell

I installed [fishfish](http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/)(a user-friendly interactive command line shell) on a Linux server, later somebody uninstalled it but I don't know it. After I run `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish` without caution, I cannot login the server now. Error message "login: no shell: No such file or directory" showed up which apparently says that shell fish do not exist anymore.

The server provides only a CLI interface, so how can I change the login shell when I cannot even login?

Comment: Do you have access to a root account?

Comment: @rahmu I ran `chsh` under account root. I changed root's shell.

Comment: @xanpeng You did it wrong, its `chsh username_to_change` from the root account.

Comment: And this would be why you should ALWAYS set the root account's shell to something basic that never gets undeleted, like `sh` or `bash`.

Comment: @Shadur Yes, I did it wrong, lesson learned: should be more careful when you are root.

Answer (score 8):

If you have access to the root account, you can change the shell for a user from there using `chsh -u user -s $SHELL`.

If you have access to the boot process, you can append `init=$SHELL` to be dropped to a single-user shell, where you can fix this, again with `chsh -u user -s $SHELL` (some systems using a two-stage boot with an initrd image may require you to use `real_init` instead). You will probably need to remount the filesystem containing `/etc/passwd` as read-write (using `mount -o remount,rw /` or similar).

Otherwise, if you can `su` into the user from another user, try `su user -c $SHELL`, or if you can ssh into the user, you could try something like `ssh user@localhost $SHELL`.

You could also boot into a live CD/USB, mount `/` and fix `/etc/passwd` manually.

Comment: Thanks. (1) As I changed login shell for root himself, so I guess method #1 cannot work.  (2) For method #2 "change boot process", I'm wondering how to remount the filesystem? I'm out of the shell, I cannot execute `mount`. I tried `init=/bin/bash` and `real_init=/bin/bash, neither of them worked. (3) For method #3, it cannot work as we have only one account, root, in the server OS.

Comment: @xanpeng I gave the command to remount the root filesystem (which is probably where you have `/etc`). You should be able to SSH in from another machine.

Answer (score 3):

i have the same problem, this solution work for me:

1. Boot with a live cd (i use debían 7.6) in live mode
2. In live terminal, get root access running the command: `passwd root`
3. Mount the disk of the partition of you crash distro
4. Go to this disk and run this command: `cat etc/shells`
5. With `nano etc/passwd` remove the fish references and put a valid console name of point 4
6. Reboot and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

When trying to login I was getting this message:
***Cannot execute /sbin/nologin: No such file or directory***

This is what I did and it worked for me.

1. I logged in the system with another account with super user privileges
2. Enter the following command:

> sudo chsh -u user -s $SHELL

where user is the account name with the problem

3. Logout of the system
4. Login with the account name that had a problem

Comment: Correction the -u should be taken out

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem in Elementary OS Loki. To resolve the issue i performed the following

1. firstly i remove everything related to zsh by *sudo apt-get remove zsh && apt-get autoremove*
2. after that i edited the */etc/passwd* file and found that shell of root user is not defined so i edited shell /bin/bash and this all help me to resolve the problem.