# /bin/false: No such file or directory | Can't login as root or do anything

Tags: freebsd

Yes, I created another topic with a guest acc and I couldn't edit or comment it so here:

I'm having a huge issue and I'm freaking out. This all started when I booted today and I couldn't connect to sftp..

I tried to fix it by messing with the sshd_config file and it might broke it.

I try to login as root ( I don't have any other account ) and this shows up:

[image]

I'm running freebsd 9.3 x64 on a virtualmachine, everything worked fine and today it all went to crap.

Please, someone who knows how can I fix this please help me because I have a ton of work in here and now I have no idea how can I get it :|

If I try to login with root through ssh I get access denied.

Comment: Well if it's a virtual machine just log into the recovery mode and reset the shell

Comment: But the password is correct, If I type a random password it says that the password is wrong.

Comment: I just commented on this same problem and asked several question which were not answered.  Apparently this user also has problems logging into stackexchange.

Comment: I think its all answered here(?).
It is a vm, I just can't login in anything.. I just want to get the files out of there.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the password is correct. It says login: /bin/false, which will not allow you to log in. See this post, it may help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40292/how-to-fix-login-no-shell-no-such-file-or-directory-when-i-can-not-even-logi

Comment: btw, the animated screenshots are unnecessary and irritating.  copy-pasting the text would have provided the same information without the irritation.

Comment: Apparently, author posted this question twice: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244282/bin-false-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: "Yes, I created another topic with a guest acc and I couldn't edit or comment it so here"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've set root's shell to `/bin/false`. You need to reboot to single user mode and use `chsh` to change it back to `/bin/csh`.

Alternatively, if you have set a password for the toor account, you can login as `toor` and `chsh -s /bin/csh root`.

Similarly, if you have `sudo` installed you can login as your normal non-root user and run `sudo chsh -s /bin/csh root`.

Or you could login as your non-root user and run `su -m` and then `chsh -s /bin/csh`.

If you can access the machine via ssh, you don't even need a valid root shell to fix it.  Just run:

```
ssh root@VM-ip chsh -s /bin/csh root
```

and enter root's password when requested.

And then create yourself a non-root user account because doing everything as root is wrong in every possible way.  the root account is for systems administration tasks, not normal usage.

Comment: I typed chsh and this showed up: http://i.imgur.com/XX25jOF.png

Comment: your root fs is mounted read-only, the machine probably crashed and the fs is inconsistent.  try running `fsck -y /dev/xxx` (where /dev/xxx is your rootfs' device node - possibly `/dev/gpt/rootfs`).  then either reboot or `mount -a`.  then try changing the shell as described above.

Comment: please stop with the screenshots.  putty is perfectly capable of copying text.

Comment: using `-y` with `fsck` is, to quote sir humphrey appleby, a _courageous decision_ ... I would leave the `-y` out until you get tired of typing `y<CR>`.

Comment: I get tired of it very, very quickly. hence the `-y`.